# What is @@ called in puppet, and what does it do?

Tags: puppet

I'm learning puppet, and have come across a part of haproxy configuration which looks like the following

```
@@haproxy::balancermember { $::fqdn:
    listening_service => 'puppet00',
    server_names      => $::hostname,
    ipaddresses       => $::ipaddress,
    ports             => '8140',
    options           => 'check',
 }
```

I'm trying to work out what the `@@` is called and what it does in this config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manifest is declaring an [exported resource](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_exported.html) for use by another node.

This allows you to create dynamic configurations that adapt to the shifting set of nodes in a given setup.